# How many times do I have to expand?

Tags: binomial-theorem

For the binomial expansion:

If a question asks you to find the co-efficient of $p^4q^7$ in the expansion $(2p-q)$$(p+q)^{10}$

I would firstly expand out $(p+q)$ correct?  But how do I know how many times I have to expand it out?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a typo? $(2p-q)(p+q)=2p^2+pq-q^2$.

Comment: @angryavian I do apologize - fixed.

Comment: "co-efficient" = "efficient with somebody". I imagine busy polynomials asking for efficient help, maybe to be developed... In brief, I think that "coefficient" doesn't need a "-"... :)

Answer (score 7):

\begin{align}
(2p-q)(p+q)^{10}&=2p\left(\sum_{i=0}^{10}\begin{pmatrix} 10 \\ i\end{pmatrix} p^{i}q^{10-i}\right) -q\left(\sum_{i=0}^{10}\begin{pmatrix} 10 \\ i\end{pmatrix} p^{i}q^{10-i}\right) \\
&=2\left(\sum_{i=0}^{10}\begin{pmatrix} 10 \\ i\end{pmatrix} p^{i+1}q^{10-i}\right) -\left(\sum_{i=0}^{10}\begin{pmatrix} 10 \\ i\end{pmatrix} p^{i}q^{11-i}\right)
\end{align}

For the first term, $p^4q^7$ term appears when $i=3$ and for the second term, $p^4q^7$ term appears when $i=4$.

Hence, the quantity of interest is

$$2\begin{pmatrix} 10 \\ 3\end{pmatrix} -\begin{pmatrix} 10 \\ 4\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: $(2p-q)$ not for $(2p-7$

Comment: oh dear, thanks for pointing out the mistake... time to change glasses.

Answer (score 2):

$$(2p-q)(p+q)^{10}=2p\sum_{i=0}^{10}\binom{10}{i} p^{i}q^{10-i} -q\sum_{i=0}^{10}\binom{10}{i}p^{i}q^{10-i}$$
$$=\sum_{i=0}^{10}2\binom{10}{i} p^{i+1}q^{10-i} -\sum_{i=0}^{10}\binom{10}{i}p^{i}q^{11-i}$$
in first sum for $i=3$ and in second sum for $i=4$ we get that
$$2\binom{10}{3}-\binom{10}{4}$$
is coefficient of $p^4q^7$

Answer (score 1):

Using the [Coefficient Extraction Operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series#Extracting_coefficients),
$$
\begin{align}
\left[p^4q^7\right](2p-q)(p+q)^{10}
&=2\left[p^4q^7\right]p(p+q)^{10}-\left[p^4q^7\right]q(p+q)^{10}\tag{1}\\[6pt]
&=2\left[p^3q^7\right](p+q)^{10}-\left[p^4q^6\right](p+q)^{10}\tag{2}\\
&=2\binom{10}{3}-\binom{10}{4}\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: the Coefficient Extraction Operator is linear
$(2)$: $\left[x^n\right]x\,f(x)=\left[x^{n-1}\right]f(x)$
$(3)$: apply the [Binomial Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) to evaluate the Coefficient Extraction Operator

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment? The binomial theorem has been used to give the coefficients of $p^3q^7$ and $p^4q^6$ in $(p+q)^{10}$.